# MySQL COUNT from 2 tables

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

I'm drawing a huge blank on something I'm sure I've done before, and is probably simple.
Alas, I'm going to ask for assistance anyways.

I have 2 tables:
`tbl_admins_groups`
`tbl_admins`

I'm pulling a query on the just the admin group table:

SELECT groupid, groupname, groupdesc FROM `tbl_admins_groups`

And now I'd like to add another column that counts the number of admin records associated to that groupid.

Here's my attempt:

```
SELECT g.groupid, g.groupname, g.groupdesc, COUNT(a.adminid) AS `admincount`
FROM `tbl_admins_groups` g, `tbl_admins` a
WHERE g.groupid = a.groupid
AND a.adminstatus = 1 
GROUP BY g.groupid
```

For some reason I'm getting just one result back. 
Is my GROUP BY incorrect?

Comment: Does `tbl_admins` contain a row for every group in `tbl_admins_groups`? If not, you may need to use a left join.

Comment: yes, each row in tbl_admins has a groupid assigned.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get their `COUNT` inside subquery and join it with `tbl_admins_groups`

```
SELECT g.groupid, g.groupname, g.groupdesc,
        a.totalCount
FROM   tbl_admins_groups g
       LEFT JOIN 
       (
            SELECT groupid, COUNT(*) totalCount
            FROM tbl_admins
            WHERE adminstatus = 1
            GROUP BY groupid
       ) a
            ON g.groupid = a.groupid
```